# Tutorials on PyObjC

Tags: objective-c, macos, pyobjc

I would like to know if there are any tutorial websites for learning PyObjC apart from the home page of the project itself. I'm enthusiastic about being able to use python to develop native code and be productive without learning how to program in some of the other more traditional compiled languages. Anywhere I could get a screencast or good beginner tuts would be excellent.

Comment: What is wrong with the home page? It seems to have several good examples.  http://pyobjc.sourceforge.net/examples/index.html

Comment: The thing is, even if you stick to PyObjC, you still have to learn Cocoa to develop Mac apps. And the hard part is Cocoa, not Objective-C.

Answer (score 2):

You could start with Will Larson's [stuff](http://lethain.com/entry/2008/aug/22/an-epic-introduction-to-pyobjc-and-cocoa/).  You could read the Apple docs and do the temperature conversion thingie.  You could do what I did and get Hillegass's book and then do the examples using PyObjC.  You could read my [stuff](http://telliott99.blogspot.com/search/label/PyObjC).  I have lots of simple examples, but I'm just an amateur.  You don't need to worry about Objective-C yet, but if you stick with it, you probably will.

And you really must learn that case matters.